# Availability zone selection in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My question is somewhat similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574689/how-does-the-ec2-api-decide-which-availability-zone) but I could not find the answer there.

I using the following code snippet to create instance.

**Code:**

```
public void test(String accessId, String accessKey){
     credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessId, accessKey);
     amazonEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
     amazonEC2Client.setEndpoint("ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com");
     RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();
     runInstancesRequest.withImageId(imageId)
        .withInstanceType("t2.micro")
        .withMinCount(2)
        .withMaxCount(2);
}
```

When I ran the above snippet I got the following error.

```
We currently do not have sufficient t2.micro capacity in zones with support for'gp2'volumes. 
Our system will be working on provisioning additional capacity. 
(Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 500; Error Code: 
InsufficientInstanceCapacity; Request ID: c1996284-c208-446a-9f4c-301d8900e503)
```

After googling I found that AWS does not have that amount of t2.micro instance at that time and it recommended to create instance in different availability zone.

But  in the code I have not provided any availability zone but the instances are being created in the `ap-northeast-1a` availability zone and throws above error and terminates.

When I created in through AWS web console it automatically created an instance in `ap-northeast-1c` without throwing any error.

Is there any way to create an instance in any available zone of that particular region where ever that instance is available programmatically ?.

My understanding is there is no or less t2.micro instance available in ap-northeast-1 region when I called the API.

Is there any API to check is Instance are available in a particular region ?.

Comment: @AvinashRaj engha vangha http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113113/avinash-and-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS do not provide an API to check what available instances there are in a particular region.

You could try one AZ, if it fails try the next AZ, and so on.

Alternatively you could use an AutoScaling group that is allowed to launch instances in different AZs. It will automatically do the above for you.

Comment: Since I haven't given AZ should not it take a AZ where the instance is available ?.

Comment: This isn't something that is documented, so it would be dangerous to assume it. I would highly suggest that you do some testing with AutoScaling :)

Comment: I agree it is dangerous to take that assumption.